# How to load a large amount of elements in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I want to create a [connect four](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/Connect_four_game.svg) game in fxml. I have already created the fxml for the board and now I want to load all the "coin fields" which are Buttons with an Image view into my Controller.
From previous experiences with fxml I learned to load an fxml element like this:

```
@FXML
Button idOfButton;
```

This is good if I have specific elements that I want to change. But since I have 42 Buttons (6*7) I don't want to do that for every Button Field... Is there any way I can do it in a different way and auto-generate it? I prepared this for-loop but since I don't know what to write into the curly braces it's still pointless :D

```
Button[] coinButtons = new Button[42];

@FXML
public Button[] loadCoinButtons() {
    for(int x=0; x<7; x++) {
        for(int y=0; y<6; y++) {
        // Stuff that loads the buttons into my buttons array
        }
    }
    return coinButtons;
}
```

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Just create the buttons in Java, instead of in FXML.

Comment: @James_D And then load it into my fxml?

Comment: BTW, why do you need 42 buttons? In Connect4, there are at most 7 possible moves.

Comment: No, don't use FXML for the buttons. Just create them directly in the controller.

Comment: @James_D ah you are right, I actually only need 7 buttons because the coins are gonna drop anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create these buttons in the Java code. Not declaring them in FXML doesn't mean they won't belong to your scene. What you have to do is give the `fx:id` tag to a container in which you would like to put more buttons, declare it in a `Controller` class with the `@FXML` annotation and then put some new `Nodes` there. Look at the simple app below (assuming all the files are in the `sample` package) - I created some buttons in FXML file and some via the Java code.

```
Main.java:

package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

sample.fxml:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<VBox fx:id="vBox" fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
        <Button text="FXML_Button_1"/>
        <Button text="FXML_Button_2"/>
        <Button text="FXML_Button_3"/>
</VBox>
```

Controller.java:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Controller {
  @FXML
  VBox vBox;

  private final int BUTTONS_NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 5;
  private final int BUTTONS_NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 5;
  private Button [][] buttons = new Button[BUTTONS_NUMBER_OF_ROWS][BUTTONS_NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];


  @FXML
  private void initialize() {
    initializeButtonsArray();
    putButtonsOnGrid();
  }

  private void initializeButtonsArray() {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < BUTTONS_NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS ; i++) {
      for (int j = 0 ; j < BUTTONS_NUMBER_OF_ROWS ; j++) {
        buttons[i][j] = new Button("Button_" + i + j);
      }
    }
  }

  private void putButtonsOnGrid() {
    GridPane buttonsGridPane = new GridPane();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < BUTTONS_NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS ; i++) {
      for (int j = 0 ; j < BUTTONS_NUMBER_OF_ROWS ; j++) {
        buttonsGridPane.add(buttons[i][j], i, j);
      }
    }
    vBox.getChildren().add(buttonsGridPane);
  }
}
```

[image: How does it look like - picture]